# Huge delay on DELETE requests with 204 response and no content in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having problem with iOS app (I'm not iOS developer, I'm responsible for API that that app uses) and DELETE requests.

API is using 204 responses with no content for DELETE requests and that have worked fine for all the client applications so far, without any problems.

The issue is that when using `NSUrlConnection` all those DELETE requests either are processed for more than 60 seconds or fail because of timeout.

This behaviour is only visible in out iOS implementations, other clients are getting response for exactly same request in less than 100ms.

Is this common behaviour? Do anyone know any fix for that that hopefully doesn't require API rebuild?

Code below was created just to emulate this behaviour and replicate problem on API development team side, but problem is the same (Access token obscured of course, authentication works fine):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  NoteablesTest

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *loadingLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_loadingLabel setHidden:true];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)didButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    NSString *url = @"https://api.noteables.com/editing-session/c180af93-ad3a-4751-a96a-dc47ff7732d4";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
    
    [request setValue:@"Bearer XXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    
    [request setValue:@"Noteables/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 8.1.3; Scale/2.00)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    
    [request setValue:@"application/vnd.api.v1+json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    
    [request setValue:@"en;q=1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
    
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

    [_loadingLabel setHidden:false];

    [NSURLConnection  sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        
        double timePassed = [start timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Elapsed: %f seconds", timePassed];
        [_loadingLabel setHidden:true];

        
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result!" message: message  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Am I satisfied with this?" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        
        [alert show];
        
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
    }];
    

}

@end
```

Comment: Please provide the iOS source code that connects to your server if you believe this to be a problem with the iOS implementation.

Comment: Sure, sorry for that, I added it to original question. I don't have access to real code of the app but as I described, behaviour is the same.

Comment: Kinda sounds like a timeout is occurring, waiting for the response.  This could be because the iOS implementation is coded to expect response data where there is none.  It's possible your host implementation has changed slightly and is no longer sending some dummy data with the response.

Comment: iOS client is new thing in the platform that's why we didn't saw this problem earlier. Is there a way to just wait for response and forget about content data?

Comment: Is your API response setting the content-length header to 0?

Comment: Actually no, and I suppose that's the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting your `content-length` header to 0.

Comment: You can delete this thank you comment all you want - if only Aaron gets to see it before deletion: Aaron, I am upvoting this so hard, I wish I could give you 1 thousand rep. I have a web api infused c# app that was returning 204's with a little comment on - this comment altered the content-length to the length of the comment (+2 chars (wtf?)) which made Safari@iOS and only this client spawn this weird timeout. Thank you. As a matter of fact: THANK YOU SO HARD, I will buy you a giant, micro-brew IPA beer of my personal favourite on the spot, if I ever meet you. I will toast to your awesomeness.

Answer (score 6):

Any HTTP request sent from an iOS device that returns both a `204` status and a non-empty response (indicated by a `content-length` header with any value but `0`) will cause the connection to run into a timeout on the device. iOS receives the `204` response, then discards the content, then reads the header and then mistakingly waits for a non-empty response to arrive.

Heads-up: the iOS simulator will NOT run into this problem. This seems to be a (real) device-only issue.

Without being able to inspect the code on the iOS client side of things, it has been suggested that this is a unintentional handling error on the HTTP request side, which means the implementation is not standard-conforming. A 204 response should ignore any content, as it is the "no content" response.

Comment: yup
this line in my drf API broke stuff on iOS:
`return Response({'detail': "Card fake-deleted"}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)`
thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Gzip was adding additional contant-length when there wasn't any.