# Mobile Safari (iPhone) has 30 sec + latency for Javascript GET requests

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-app-engine, mobile-safari

I am developing a mobile web application: www.bazmo.com. When I test the site, the latency of the GET JS requests can get up to 30 seconds. It basically seems broken to the user.

Here is how I recreate the error:

- Turn off cellular (wifi only)
- Clear History and Website Data
- Open safari and go to a page like www.bazmo.com/best/laptops
- Then click on the logo to go to the home page at which point it gets stuck for 30 seconds before the JS files load if they are not cached

I sometimes can catch it on Web Inspector and it just shows the JS not being loaded for 30 seconds.

What am I missing here.

I just use simple:  to insert the files in.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around but not a permanent solution. The website uses Google App Engine.

The line:

script src="/javascript/categoryScript.js"> just did not work on safari mobile.

However the line:

script src="yourid.appspot.com/javascript/categoryScript.js"> does since it is trying to retrieve from another domain.

This helps provide a workaround but it is pretty bad form that I can't use the path from the domain itself.

I have been trying to find a way to make that work but no dice so far.

Comment: My work around was not using a relative path and using my staging path instead. Not the cleanest of fixes but worked at the time.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and problem was that our back-end returned `204` status and not `200`. **BUT** this issue was caused by using `HTTP OPTIONS` method and not `GET` (but it can be caused by the same thing).

Related reading:

- [Huge delay on DELETE requests with 204 response and no content in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684209/huge-delay-on-delete-requests-with-204-response-and-no-content-in-objective-c)
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70226
- https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/6874